MySQL Exec_Master_Log_Pos is slow to update in replica compared to actual data
I'm trying to use Exec_Master_Log_Pos from SHOW REPLICA STATUS to check whether the replica is caught up to the master. However, Exec_Master_Log_Pos appears to take a while to update.
When I add a row to the master, I can correctly query the row in the replica within 30 ms. In addition, the Read_Master_Log_Pos from SHOW REPLICA STATUS also updates to the correct value within 30 ms.
So the data in the replica is updated within 30 ms, but I have to wait ~300 ms for Exec_Master_Log_Pos to update to the right value.
A few questions come to mind:

Why is Exec_Master_Log_Pos so slow to update?
Should I be using another method to check whether my replica has caught up to a specific timestamp on the master? Perhaps I should just write a value to the master and read it in a loop on the replica instead of relying on SHOW REPLICA STATUS?

I am spinning up MySQL 8.0 master and replica with docker-compose.yml and following these directions to set up the MySQL replica

Are any heavy queries been executing on the replica ?

No, it is idle. I did notice the time to Exec log update get even worse when heavy queries are being executed on the master.

It seems that the slave needs more time to process the data. Master/Slave servers do they have the same parameters and configurations?

Basic vanilla config for both of them from the Docker image. The issue is that if I read the data from the replica, I get the correct (replicated) data. But the Exec_Master_Log_Pos value doesn't update to the expected value for a while longer.
